# How to count the number of cell pairs containing x and y values larger/smaller than the mean in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, statistics

I have an excel spreadsheet with paired data for 105 different pairs. I'm trying to conduct a chi square test, but I first need to find frequencies for the number of pairs where x is greater than the x mean and y is greater than the y mean, x is greater than the x mean and y is lower than the y mean, x is lower than the x mean and y is lower than the y mean, and x is lower than the x mean and y is greater than y mean.

Is there a formula that can help me with this? I've tried using countif but the answers it gives me always add up to more than the total amount of data. I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always helpful to post a screenshot of your data.  If you upload one to imgur.com, you can edit your question to add the link.

Let's assume that your x and y values are in Columns A and B, starting in Row 2 (column headings in Row 1) and that your x mean and y mean are in C2 and D2.

Since you have more than one condition to check for, you need to use [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).  This formula in E2 will give the number of pairs with x greater than the x-mean and y greater than thr y-mean.

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A126,">"&C2,B2:B126,">"&D2)`

Change the ">" characters appropriately for the other three statistics that you need to calculate.

Note: I am on an iPad, and unable to test this, but it should do what you're looking for. Hope this helps and good luck.